# How to get the last line / paragraph of a selection in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have an odd behavior in selections in a `RichTextBox`:

In a selection where the last line of the selection is completely selected, the `.End` property points not to the line last line (paragraph) of the selection but to the following paragraph.
Screenshots of the behavior:

**Selected Text**

[image]

**The `.Text` property shows the correct content**

[image]

**But the `.End` property points to the following `paragraph`**

[image]

I could iterate through the selection and compare the content of the `.Text` property with the runs in the paragraphs and …. But is there an easier way to get the last paragraph of a selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this way to get the last line in a selection. Seems to work.

```
// In my case "this" is the RichTextBox itself, because I work in a derived class from RichTextBox
Paragraph lastLineInSelection = this.Selection.End.Paragraph;
if (this.Selection.End.IsAtLineStartPosition)
{
    Block previousBlock = this.Selection.End.Paragraph.PreviousBlock;
    while (previousBlock is Paragraph == false && previousBlock != null)
        previousBlock = previousBlock.PreviousBlock;

    if (previousBlock != null)
        lastLineInSelection = (previousBlock as Paragraph);
}
```